# Android build compilation using ant resulted an errror "UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException"

Tags: android, ant

I'm working on an Android Project which gets compiled using ant on a build server.
It has couple of library projects.Since the Android sdk update,No build has worked.
it bailed out with following error

Please find the log below

```
[dex] Converting compiled files and external libraries into <project>/bin/classes.dex...
INFO  -
[dx] UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
[dx] java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3158
[dx]     at com.android.dx.merge.IndexMap.adjustString(IndexMap.java:112)
[dx]     at com.android.dx.merge.IndexMap.adjust(IndexMap.java:212)
[dx]     at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$7.read(DexMerger.java:505)
[dx]     at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$7.read(DexMerger.java:499)
[dx]     at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.readUnsortedValues(DexMerger.java:333)
[dx]     at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeUnsorted(DexMerger.java:302)
[dx]     at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeAnnotations(DexMerger.java:499)
[dx]     at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexBuffers(DexMerger.java:166)
[dx]     at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:186)
[dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:300)
[dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:232)
[dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:174)
[dx]     at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:91)
```

Any Help is appreciated.

Comment: Android Tools team has given a work around for  this issue in Revision 21.0.1 (December 2012) http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/tools-notes.html
add the following setting to your project.properties file: "dex.disable.merger=true" This will fix the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue of the **Android SDK**.

A workaround would be to use `dex.disable.merger=true` in `project.properties`

Comment: Thanks it worked.But can you explain it to me in detail why it worked?